# Create a path of files and folder under linux ubuntu in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, directory, filepath

I have the following code

```
system("mkdir workspace");
char*files = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(address));
sprintf(files, " %s", address);
char*command = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(address) + 256);
sprintf(command, "mkdir -p workspace/%s", files);
system(command);
```

The problem is that I want to create the folder address inside the folder workspace like workspace > www.google.com .. but instead these two folders are created in same folder and I don't know what I am doing wrong. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory allocated for `files` is too small (the two bytes for the `\0` and the whitespace are missing in the size) and `mkdir -p workspace/ www.google.com` does indeed result in the two directories to reside in the same parent directory because of the single space introduced in the `sprintf`.